# Java Retrieving user data from firebase database and storing in variables Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have looked everywhere on stackoverflow and can't find my issue what i am trying to retrive is a users id from the database to show all users that are online except that user, however all the database info is being stored except the id resulting in the following crash

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>           at USER.UsersFragment$1.onDataChange(UsersFragment.java:63).

Here is my users file

```
    public class User {
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String birthday;
    private String email;
    private String imageURL;

    public User(String id, String username, String first_name, String last_name, String birthday, String email, String imageURL) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.email = email;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public User() {

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }
}
```

Here is how I am storing my info into the variables, the line where it crashes is labeled CRASH.

```
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsernames.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    assert user != null;
                    if(!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) { <-CRASH
                        mUsernames.add(user);
                    }
                    //Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "", user.getId());
                }

                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsernames);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please post your database structure

Comment: user.getId is null

Comment: Edit http://puu.sh/EnwU3.png

Comment: What are you expecting to happen that's different than what you're observing?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yeah I found that out, I'm just not sure why its not being set like all the other variables I have tested ex. Birthday shows up perfect

Comment: @DougStevenson It's crashing rather then showing my user list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your database, you have more than one record. But only one record contains the field `id`.

Therefore when retrieving the data it is retrieving from the node that does not contain the node `id` and return an error.

Comment: What are the steps to fixing it? separate the record's?

Comment: and an `id` for every user same as `bluefoot`

Comment: `Bluefoot` has an `id` field, you need to add an `id` field for `vileWolf` and for `murdersalt` and for any other user under node `users`

Comment: Holy moly I just added the id's and it works, THANK you so much lol. A dumb mistake from my sleep deprived mind, now I can rest easy. Thanks again. http://puu.sh/Enx34.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your database records don't have a field called "id", which means that getId() is always going to return null.  The data is simply not there.

It looks like you probably want to use the key of the snapshot from `snapshot.getKey()`.

Comment: The user I am using does under BlueFoot http://puu.sh/EnwTf.png

EDIT: In addition I also switched "id" to "user_id as the database has on top and that doesn't work either.

I will give the snapshot.getKey(). a try and report back, thank you

Comment: How would I pass the key over to the User.class as I have now?

Comment: Call setId() the data you want in there?

Comment: Its all good, thanks for your fast help, I just seem to have forgotten to add  ids for old accounts when they weren't created with them in the database.

Comment: It looks like you do have IDs in there in the key of each record.  Are you saying those IDs are not what you want?